# remove bottom divider of a android ExpandedListView

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, expandablelistview

So I am trying to remove the top and bottom (or header and footer if you will) dividers from the listsviews within each group of a ExpandableListView.  I saw this link ([Remove the bottom divider of an android ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961999/remove-bottom-divider-of-a-android-listview)) but that does not seem to work with the ExpandableListView.  Does anyone have a way to do this within code or XML markup?  I can disable them all together and do it with in the item layout, but since I share that with nother list I do not really want to go that route unless I have too.

I am targeting Honeycomb (3.1).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `android:childDivider` xml attribute to 0px?