# How can I add a divider in the bottom of a list in Android?

Tags: android

I have added a divider as images to list view. but it is not showing at the bottom of the list. Why?

Comment: Could you add your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because divider are used just to separate listitems from one another.last item does not need to be separated so it won't show you the divider at the bottom. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961999/remove-bottom-divider-of-a-android-listview) might help you( though it is reverse then what you asked).

Comment: If you check the system listviews, all of them have a divider after the last item. Your comment makes no sense.