# Remove divider between listview header and first item

Tags: android, android-listview, header, footer, divider

From the title of my question, my problem is clear. I have a custom listView and a header and some items. Ofcourse, I have added dividers between all the items. Only thing I don't want is the divider between header and the first item.
However, below code is not working.. I also want to know the exact work of this line

```
list.setHeaderDividerEnabled(false);
```

I have searched and tried a lot also visited this links but no luck..

[Empty space between listview header and first item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119132/empty-space-between-listview-header-and-first-item)

[Android listView unwanted space between header view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095214/android-listview-unwanted-space-between-header-view)

Thanks in advance.

Update!

```
public class ListView extends android.widget.ListView {

private OnScrollListener onScrollListener;
private Onscroll onscrollObj;

public ListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    onCreate(context, null, null);
}

public ListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    onCreate(context, attrs, null);
}

public ListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    onCreate(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@SuppressWarnings("UnusedParameters")
private void onCreate(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, Integer defStyle) {
    setListeners();
}

private void setListeners() {
    super.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        private int oldTop;
        private int oldFirstVisibleItem;

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            if (onScrollListener != null) {
                onScrollListener.onScrollStateChanged(view, scrollState);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if (onScrollListener != null) {
                onScrollListener.onScroll(view, firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount);
            }

            if (onscrollObj != null) {
                onDetectedListScroll(view, firstVisibleItem);
            }
        }

        private void onDetectedListScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem) {
            View view = absListView.getChildAt(0);
            int top = (view == null) ? 0 : view.getTop();

            if (firstVisibleItem == oldFirstVisibleItem) {
                if (top > oldTop) {
                    onscrollObj.onUpScrolling();
                } else if (top < oldTop) {
                    onscrollObj.onDownScrolling();
                }
            } else {
                if (firstVisibleItem < oldFirstVisibleItem) {
                    onscrollObj.onUpScrolling();
                } else {
                    onscrollObj.onDownScrolling();
                }
            }

            oldTop = top;
            oldFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void setOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener onScrollListener) {
    this.onScrollListener = onScrollListener;
}

public void setOnDetectScrollListener(Onscroll onDetectScrollListener) {
    this.onscrollObj = onDetectScrollListener;
}
}
```

Comment: it's easier for people to help you if they have some relevant **piece of code** to work on - please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: I have added the link already I have tried on and please explain the exact work of list.setHeaderDividerEnabled(false);

Comment: setHeaderDivider**s**Enabled(boolean) "Enables or disables the drawing of the divider for header views", at least that's what the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setHeaderDividersEnabled%28boolean%29) says. - I can't tell why this does not work for your app because I can't see *your code*. Something like a ["minimal, complete and verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be nice.

Comment: I have used that code for my listView; i don't think that is the reason of not working as it extends the ListView as well

Comment: can you add the solution after knowing what is the custom for my listView @0X0nosugar

Comment: Thanks for posting the code. (I simply wanted to make sure there was no simple typo at the source of the problem, happens to all of us) I've just looked into the ListView source code (grepcode.com). And started wondering: what if the header dividers are the *dividers between two or more header elements*? Up to now I always thought: header is a kind of singleton. Could you try and add some headers and do some experiments with dividers enabled/disabled?

Comment: ok, I would do that experiment but after trying the answer of Zhli I got that my custom class is the reason of not working for list.setHeaderDividerEnabled(false);
now I am searching the answer that after Override that method super class I can't get my expected result

Comment: 1. you can indeed have two or more headers and the "headerDividersEnabled" stuff is referring to dividers between them.  -  2. I can't test with your class because I don't know "Onscroll.java"   -  3. I think one solution for your problem is to *disable* any divider and then like some of the answers indicated you can [in the getView() of the list adapter] add your own "1dp" line at the bottom of each list row *except the last*. Which one is the last? position = adapter.getCount() - 1

Comment: Sorry I don't have the time to post an answer now, anybody feel free to copy what's useful to their answers from my comments.

Comment: Onscroll.java is nothing but a simple interface to access the methods from the fragment. ok, thanks for your valuable comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can remove all divider by `android:dividerHeight="0dp" android:divider="@null"` Now for each item of listview you add a `View` with `width` equal `match_parrent`, and `height` equal `1dp` at bottom

Comment: sorry but your solution have a problem for the last item of the list as it will add the view at last

Comment: Works perfectly! @Md.Asaduzzaman you can simply check if it is the last item of the list and hide the divider View.

Answer (score 8):

I use the property in xml "android:headerDividersEnabled="false"" ,  and It works fine. And If you want to custom the divider between header and first item, I suppose you could do something in the bottom of header layout to pretend it is a divider.

[image: List View with Header]

My code:

Main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


<ListView
    android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp"
    android:divider="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/my_list_view"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="3px"
    />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Bind(R.id.my_list_view)
ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    initviews();
}

private void initviews() {
    View view = View.inflate(this,R.layout.headerview,null);
    listView.addHeaderView(view);
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, getData(),
            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "img", "title", "info" },
            new int[] { R.id.img, R.id.title, R.id.info });
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}


private List<Map<String, Object>> getData() {
    List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("img", R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    map.put("title", "php");
    map.put("info", "for server");
    list.add(map);

    map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("img",  R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    map.put("title", "java");
    map.put("info", "stable");
    list.add(map);

    map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("img",  R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    map.put("title", "C++");
    map.put("info", "cool and hard");
    list.add(map);

    map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("img",  R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    map.put("title", "python");
    map.put("info", "pretty clean");
    list.add(map);

    map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("img",  R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    map.put("title", "hello");
    map.put("info", "every thing");
    list.add(map);

    map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("img",  R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    map.put("title", "world");
    map.put("info", "hello world");
    list.add(map);

    return list;
}

}
```

Comment: Only a major difference from your code is the custom listView class that i have used for my listView, Please see the update above

Comment: Apparenttly， “android:headerDividersEnabled” is the right answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
    <ListView
    android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    />          

    or do this, 

don't add a listview.headerview(view);
instead, add a header view in the xml design and do like this
<LinearLayout>
<layout header design>
<Listview>
</LinearLayout>          
Don't provide space between header and Listview.
```

Comment: and how would this help to **REMOVE** the divider between listview header and first item?

Comment: Rather than setting programmatically, change the same in xml file might work, just trying to help@0X0nosugar.

Comment: I don't know whether "false" will do the trick. But "true" simply could not be the solution :) -  I think I would like to see more code in the question, the xml attribute/ method seems quite straightforward, so I wonder what is "custom" about the listview

Comment: saw the true after you comment only bro.. :-), @0X0nosugar

Comment: I got the solution from your or answer. But the first one I am not sure and can you explain that how that(first one) would solve the problem..

Comment: So the xml is set first , so it's better to set headerDividerEnabled="false" in xml than setting it through java code. As the Listview is refreshed every time you scroll through item. The java code you use to disable became not useful. As it is set only once.. @Md.Asaduzzaman

Comment: Ofcourse I have added headerDividerEnabled="false" to the xml first and then also tried to add by java code  but neither is working

Comment: okay then I am not sure , why first one is not working..if my second one is working please mark it as answer. @Md.Asaduzzaman..

Answer (score 0):

This Same can be achieved by using
recyclerView.removeItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
..
..
..
This Basically Removes any kind of item decoration.
(You guys can watch item decorations by hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + right click on PC on the item decorations)

Comment: I think it's better to add example code in the answer. To just refer to some link or component, i suggest to add it as a comment instead of answer.